# DocuSign Connect Integration - Attachments

Tags: docusignapi

I have the DocuSign button configured on 2 Salesforce objects (Accounts and Opportunities). On completion of each DocuSign document/envelope, I would like the signed PDF document attached to its respective object (either the Opp or the Account) in the 'Notes and Attachments' section.

To achieve this, I created 2 custom DocuSign objects via the DocuSign console - Preferences > Connect > Salesforce > Add Object. I have configured these to attach to their respective object (if sent from Account object it attaches to Account, if sent from Opp object it attaches to Opp).

The first DocuSign custom object for sending via Account works fine. It attaches the PDF to the Account object upon completion. When it is sent from the Opp however, it does attach the PDF to the Opportunity object upon completion. However, since the Opp is the child object of the Account, the attachment also automatically appears at the Account level. Now up to this point it's no problem. The issue I face is that it also runs the first DocuSign custom object and attaches the PDF directly to the Account as well - which means all DocuSign attachments resulting from Opportunities are duplicated at the Account level.

I've checked the DocuSign settings/configurations and cannot find anything to exclude running the first custom DocuSign object if the origination Salesforce object is Opportunity. DocuSign support have advised that they don't provide support for custom objects. Has anyone come across this? Any help would be much appreciated!